# Check and replace the request url or body from nginx

Tags: nginx, character, arabic, replacewith, farsi

I want to replace the body of request from Arabic character with Persian one in Nginx.
For example, replace the Arabic 'ي' with Persian 'ی' or add a custom parameter to API route. How can I check the request from the beginning and replace it with Persian character?

Answer (score 1):

You must use the Lua in Nginx.
Lua is a programming language designed primarily for embedded use in applications.

[Lua programming language](https://www.lua.org/)

[Nginx Wiki - Lua](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/lua/)

It's easy to use, Just three steps:

1. Create a file with Lua extension

```
ngx.req.read_body()

local body = ngx.req.get_body_data() or ''

body = ngx.re.gsub(body, "ي", "ی") -- remove id and name
body = ngx.re.gsub(body, "ك", "ک") -- remove id and name

ngx.req.set_body_data(body)
```

2. Add file path inside server block in Nginx config file

```
server {
    access_by_lua_file "/var/www/lua/gateway_access.lua";
}
```

3. Test the Nginx config.

```
sudo nginx -t
```

4. Restart the Nginx service.

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```